# Laravel Broadcast authentication

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io

How do I authenticate an user to a channel with a custom auth method?

For example, in my app I use a token auth (stored in the db for each user) for my API, passed via header and read by a custom middleware.

How do I control the access with these custom auth methods for channels? How would be the client and server side? I am using socket.io and the Laravel docs are quite unclear of how auth methods works for sockets.

**USE CASE:**

I have users stored in DB with default Laravel migration. However, how my app is just the API, it is stateless, then, rather than using `remember_token` to store session tokens, I use it to store an unique authentication token, generated in the login endpoint.

Every endpoint of the API, the request pass through a middleware, where the user is retrieved by the token present in the headers

```
$token = Request::header('X-token');

$request->user = User::findByToken($token);

return $next($request);
```

Now the question comes in. Laravel docs isn't much clear on how private channels works.

How would a broadcast client pass the mentioned token and get authorized to join a given channel?

Comment: Hey @Luiz I'm still not sure what are you trying to figure out ?

Comment: I want to know how to authorize an user to a given private channel if I don't use the Laravel default authentication method (for instance, JWT or other token method).

Comment: @Luiz can you provide some code examples for what you've tried already and where you feel you're missing knowledge?

Comment: @Leith sure, updated the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Laravel documentation on broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting) is pretty comprehensive about this, although it doesn't go into minute detail on client libraries that it doesn't support out of the box.

In this case, you're wanting the [section on authorizing channels](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels). From the docs:

> In the `BroadcastServiceProvider` included with your Laravel application, you will see a call to the  `Broadcast::routes` method. This method will register the `/broadcasting/auth` route to handle authorization requests

When defining broadcast routes, the currently authenticated user is passed automatically as a parameter. Since you're wanting to change the authentication mechanism *ahead* of the broadcast route definition so that the correct user is passed along, your broadcast client would pass along the token (however you like - HTTP header, URL parameter, POST data, etc.) and then you would customise the `/broadcasting/auth` route to parse that data and use it to authenticate the user. From there you would use the standard `Broadcast::channel()` definitions to ensure that the authenticated user is also an authorized user on that channel.

As per the documentation, `Broadcast::routes()` takes an optional array of `$attributes` for it to use the `web` middleware. From [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php#L65):

```
$attributes = $attributes ?: ['middleware' => ['web']];
```

So if you wish, you may change the middleware authentication to `'api'` by passing it to the `Broadcast::routes()` call (or any other standard route parameters).

Since [the route is already created for you](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php#L68), if you want to customise it at a lower level that route functions/middleware then you would need to change the `auth()` method on whichever `BroadcastProvider` you're using. More specifically, when the route is set up, it [calls the `authenticate()` method on the `BroadcastController`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php#L68), which in turn simply [calls the `auth()` method on the `Broadcast` facade](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastController.php#L19). The facade would then call whichever provider you're using - there are [a few providers defined out of the box](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.5/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters) which should give you a good starting point if you want to write your own. That being said, as long as you don't have a problem with the provider itself, it's probably easier to just write your own middleware and pass that to `Broadcast::routes()` as an attribute if you need something particular with your authentication (if it differs from the `api` authentication middleware).

As an extra, since you've tagged this with [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io), you may also want to read up on [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo). There's also a section on talking to `socket.io` specifically in the [broadcasting introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#introduction).

Comment: Yes, I've seen about Echo. But what if I cannot use Echo or if I use another language rather than JavaScript at my client? Anyways. About this part: "When defining broadcast routes, the currently authenticated user is passed automatically as a parameter" it seems to be only for web authenticated users, and NOT API users.
About "and then you would customise the /broadcasting/auth route to parse that data and use it to authenticate the user" is not clear. Would I create a route and controller for this? What would this receive and return? When is this route called at the process?

Comment: @Luiz have updated my answer with more specific detail and references to the Laravel source. It doesn't really matter what client you're using to consume it, the note about Echo was just added for interest if you hadn't seen it. You probably just need to adjust the middleware being passed to `Broadcast::routes()` to use your `api` authentication.

Answer (score 5):

On top of Leith's answer, those scratching head and wondering why creating a custom middleware and using it in `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` would throw back an error.

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['custom.middleware']]);
        
    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

Inside `Broadcaster.php` there is a method called `retrieveUser()` which should `return $request->user()` as a result of successful authentication from within your custom middleware.

In my case, I was trying to pass `access token` to API's custom middleware; and once authenticating the user, I simply passed on my original request `return $next($request)`

For the above code to work, I had to fetch the `user` model by `access token` and then merge it to the original request like so

```
$request->merge(['user' => $user ]);

$request->setUserResolver(function () use ($user) {
    return $user;
});

return $next($request);
```

So now `retrieveUser()` method from `Broadcaster.php` is able to retrieve the authenticated user with `return $request->user()` command, and it gets passed to `Broadcast::channel` method as a first parameter

```
Broadcast::channel('private-channel-name', function ($user) {
    // if you get here, you've been authenticated (within a custom middleware)
    return true;
});
```

Comment: i am also facing similar issue i think it will resolve my issue,may i know it will return user object  ?

Comment: It certainly did for me

Comment: That's a great way to inject the user to the request, since I'm retrieving the user from other project with different mechanism, that's actually worked with me on Laravel 10.x the only thing is the `$request->merge(['user' => $user ]);` isn't required and it actually throw an error complaining about using scalar type